# Create proper pdf file for printing with wkhtmltopdf

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

In docs of [**wkhtmltopdf**](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/) I cannot find any hint about how to change the print border. I've marked it with a green line in the image below.

I have

```
body {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```

and all tables are `100%` in width. The wrapper around the tables is `26cm` in width.
Any ideas how to reduces the white spaces around the content?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very complicated issue with wkhtmltopdf. Getting absolutely 100% wide content is afaik impossible, you always wind up with (less than 1mm) borders on the right and the bottom currently. I would suggest playing around with the settings to see which way you could get it to work for you. I would Love to see how you progress with this issue (Also to see if there are other print issues like CMYK battles).

What is your wkhtmltopdf command used to conver the file; have you specified margins there? Try a command like `wkhtmltopdf.exe -B 0 -R 0 -L 0 -T 0 content.html 3.pdf`. You might also want `--disable-smart-shrinking`.

With content like

```
<html>
    <head />
    <body bgcolor="red" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
        <table style="width: 100%; background-color:cyan; margin:0; padding:0;">
            <tr><td>MAGICAL PONIES</td></tr>
        </table>
        <p>bla</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

You get output like

[image: Screenshot of converted pdf]

Good luck, have fun :)

Comment: Oh and also, try to add things like a very long multi-page <ol> to see how the page breaking algorithm affects the bgcolor, that is a really good thing to test with. Also, testing with very long tables is very interesting (and points out many issues). There is a new tr breaking algorithm patch release for wkhtmltopdf but it will be some time before it reaches us users :)